# Locking a List (of Class)

Tags: vb.net

I have written a program that sucks up data from hundreds of csv files, then posts that data into a `List (of Class)` called `ENTRY_ENTRY`.

After the data has been put into there, I need to reorganize the data into a hierarchy, indicating levels and so on.  I start out by determining which `ENTRY_` lines are top of the hierarchy.

This info is stored in the List called `LIST_LIST`.

To do this, I iterate through the `LIST_LIST` list, then pick out matching info in the original List `ENTRY_ENTRY`, copy the values into a new class instance `Entry_F`, manipulate the data, and then add the information to a new `List (of Class)` called `ENTRY_FINAL`.  I also track which `ENTRY_` line was the last one to be run, then return to it.

All that coding is working fine.

One field in the Class tracks what level in the hierarchy each line has.

I wrote the code so that there was no revisions made back to the `ENTRY_ENTRY` List, but something is getting written back to `ENTRY_ENTRY`.

Is there a way to lock the `ENTRY_ENTRY` List once it has been set?

Partial code below.

```
 Public Sub levels()

        For Each List_ As LIST_ARRAY In LIST_LIST
        If List_.List_TopLevel = True Then ' finds top level parts sheets
            'MsgBox(List_.List_FileName & " : Top level : " & List_.List_Ref)

            templevel1 = List_.List_Ref
            For Each ENTRY_ As ENTRY_ARRAY In ENTRY_ENTRY
                If ENTRY_.Entry_List_Ref = templevel1 Then ' Checks for same List Ref

                    entry_F = ENTRY_
                    ' entry_f.Entry_Level = ENTRY_.Entry_Level 'increases level 



                    Entry_Final.Add(entry_F) 'adds line to final array

                    If entry_f.Entry_LinkRef <> "" Then
                        entry_1 = ENTRY_

                        sublevel2()

                    End If



                End If

            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub sublevel2()
    'MsgBox("Sublevel2 start " & entry_f.Entry_LIST_FileName & " : " & entry_f.Entry_LinkRef & " : " & entry_f.Entry_Level)
    'For Each ENTRY_f As ENTRY_ARRAY In Entry_Final.ToArray
    If entry_f.Entry_LinkRef <> "" Then
        templevel2 = entry_f.Entry_LinkRef
        'MsgBox("templevel assigned")
        For Each ENTRY_ As ENTRY_ARRAY In ENTRY_ENTRY.ToArray
            If ENTRY_.Entry_List_Ref = templevel2 Then
                'MsgBox("found child")


                entry_f = ENTRY_
                entry_f.Entry_Level = entry_f.Entry_Level + entry_1.Entry_Level 'increases level 

                Entry_Final.Add(entry_f) 'adds line to final array
                ' MsgBox("added line")

                If entry_f.Entry_LinkRef <> "" Then

                    entry_2 = ENTRY_
                    sublevel3()

                End If

            End If
            'MsgBox("Finished " & ENTRY_.Entry_PartNo & " : " & ENTRY_.Entry_LIST_FileName & " : " & templevel2)
        Next

        ENTRY_ = entry_1


    End If
    MsgBox("next child")



End Sub
```

`Sublevel3()` is a lower level version of `Sublevel2()`

Where am I writing updated information back to the `ENTRY_ENTRY` list?

Comment: Impossible to say.  Since ENTRY_ENTRY is apparently a global variable, it could be written to from any part of your code anywhere.

Comment: One starting point however would be to tell us what "updated information" is being written back to ENTRY_ENTRY and how you know this is happening.

Comment: I run a csv file that lists all the ENTRY_ENTRY lines both before and after running this code above.  Before, the data is good, afterwards, it is bad. The only data that is being altered between the ENTRY_ENTRY lines is the value in Entry_.Entry_Level

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code/your question is hard to understand, but I guess the problem is this:

> ...pick out matching info in the original List `ENTRY_ENTRY`, copy the values into a new class instance `Entry_F`, manipulate the data, and then add the information to a new `List (of Class)` called `ENTRY_FINAL`.

It seems you are talking about this part of your code:

```
For Each ENTRY_ As ENTRY_ARRAY In ENTRY_ENTRY.ToArray
    If ENTRY_.Entry_List_Ref = templevel2 Then
        entry_f = ENTRY_
        entry_f.Entry_Level = entry_f.Entry_Level + entry_1.Entry_Level 'increases level 
        Entry_Final.Add(entry_f)
        ...
```

Be aware that you are *not* creating a new instance of your class here:

```
entry_f = ENTRY_
```

If you change `entry_f`, like you do here:

```
entry_f.Entry_Level = entry_f.Entry_Level + entry_1.Entry_Level 'increases level
```

your changing the same instance that is in the list `ENTRY_ENTRY`, because `entry_f` and `ENTRY_` are references to the same object.

You have to create a *new* object instead and add that to `Entry_Final`.

Comment: I added
        Public entry_f As Object
to match the global ENTRY_ object in the initial class declaration.  It did not fix the issue.

Comment: @user2175620 - It doesn't matter if it's a global or local variable.  If both variables refer to the same object, changes using either variable will be reflected in the other.

Comment: I am confused.  I have created two separate objects, ENTRY_ and entry_f.  I make one equal to the other.  I thought that would make the two as separate objects.  
How can I set one to be equal to the other, then modify one without changing the original?  I'm still new at this, so adding code would be helpful.